# What is ":" doing in this beginners java example program using generics?

Tags: java, loops, foreach

Okay so I need help understanding something. I understand how "? :" are used together but reading over some beginning Java stuff I see this situation popping up in a few places. Most recently is this...

```
public static <U> void fillBoxes(U u, List<Box<U>> boxes) {
    for (Box<U> box : boxes) {
        box.add(u);
    }
}
```

What I am confused about is what exactly ":" is doing. Any help would be appreciated. I am looking at this example on a page at Oracle's website, located here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is Java's for-each looping construct. It has nothing to do with generics per-se or: is not for use exclusively with generics. It's shorthand that says: `for every type box in the collection named boxes do the following...`

Here's the [link to the official documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Simpler code sample: (instead of managing generics performing a summation of an int array)

```
int[] intArray = {1,5,9,3,5};
int sum = 0;
for (int i : intArray) sum += i;
System.out.println(sum);
```

> Output: 23

Comment: +1.  Just wanted to add that I like to read the ':' as "in" when I read the code to myself (as you've done in your answer).

Comment: @Ian: I was actually going to throw in a C# example showing the in keyword... better placed here though to not confuse the answer. C# version: `foreach (int i in collection_of_ints) { /*do stuff*/ }`

Comment: A minor note: the wording this answer implies that only those objects of type `Box<U>` will be iterated; actually it will iterate all objects in the collection and implicitly cast each to `Box<U>`.  If generics have been used consistently, all elements in the collection will in fact be of type `Box<U>`.  I only mention this because a newbie could interpret it to mean elements of type `Box<U>` are selected out of the collection of `Object`s.

Answer (score 2):

That's the "foreach" form of the `for` loop.  It is syntactic sugar for getting an iterator on the collection and iterating over the entire collection.

It's a shortcut to writing something like:

```
for (Iterator<Box<U>> it = boxes.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Box<U> box = it.next();
    box.add(u);
}
```

For more see [this Oracle page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) which specifically talks about the "foreach" loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to iterate over the container, in this case a List. It executes the loop once for each object in the `boxes` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is an enhanced for-each loop added in Java 1.5 to iterate efficiently through elements of collections.

Further detailed explanation is available at Java doc guide itself.http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html