# For loop in the form of : "for (A b : c)" in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach

This is the first time that I've seen this kind of syntax :

```
// class Node
public class Node { 

...
...

}

public class Otherclass { ... }

Otherclass graph = new Otherclass();

// getSuccessors is a method of Otherclass class 

Node currentNode ;

List<Node> successors = graph.getSuccessors(currentNode);

// weird for loop 

for (Node son : successors) { 

// do something 

}
```

What is that for loop ? some kind of a Matlab syntax ?

Is there any other way to write that for loop ?

Regards

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is ":" doing in this beginners java example program using generics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039211/what-is-doing-in-this-beginners-java-example-program-using-generics)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734550/in-the-for-function

Comment: Its a new syntax which was added in Java 5.0 eight years ago. :P

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is ":" doing in this beginners java example program using generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039211/what-is-doing-in-this-beginners-java-example-program-using-generics)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a for each loop. You could also write it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < successors.size(); i++) {
    Node son = successors.get(i);
}
```

Though the only time I'd personally do that is when the index is needed for doing something other than accessing the element.

Comment: A for-each loop uses iterators, so it would be more formally correct to say that it can be written as:
`for (Iterator<Node> it = successors.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Node son = it.next();
}`
For the special case of Lists, however, the code example in Anthony's answer is functionally equivalent.

Comment: But the performance might be a lot worse if you use "get" and the list doesn't support random access.

Answer (score 10):

That is a **[`for-each`](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html)** loop (also called an `enhanced-for`.)

```
for (type var : arr) { //could be used to iterate over array/Collections class
    body-of-loop
}
```

> The basic for loop was extended in Java 5 to make iteration over
>   arrays and other collections more convenient. This newer for statement
>   is called the enhanced for or for-each

**[(Documentation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)**

Answer (score 4):

It is the enhanced for statement. See section [14.14.2. The enhanced for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) 
 of the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 3):

It is called `Enhanced for-loop`. It basically iterates over a Collection by fetching each element in sequence. So you don't need to access elements on index.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int val: list) {
    System.out.println(val);  // Prints each value from list
}
```

See [**§14.14.2 - Enhanced for loop**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) section of Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 2):

it means "for each `son` in `successors`, where the type of `son` is `Node`"

Answer (score 2):

This is one representation of your for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<successors.size();i++){

        Node myNode = successors.get(i);
    }
```

This is not a for loop but still you could do this.

```
Iterator<Node> itr = successors.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Node myNode = itr.next();
        // your logic
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it is called enhanced for loop, instead of using iterator to iterate over a collection you can simply use this for loop

using iterators

```
Iterator<String> i=a.iterator();

while(i.hasNext())
{
String s=i.next();
}
```

you can simply use the enhanced for loop.

```
for(String s : a)
{
 .. do something
}
```

so it is just a syntactic sugar introduced in Java 5, that do the same functionality of the iterators and it uses the iterator internally.
The class should implement the Iterator interface in order to use this for loop

```
class Node<T> implements Iterator<String>{

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public String next() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```